# LSM6DS0 accelerometer reading with HAL_I2C_Master

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, i2c

I try to read the accelerometer on LSM6DS0 with the HAL_I2C_Master. I am coding with truestudio c and my board is STM32l476RG. My slaveaddress is 1101011xb so D7/D6 for R/W. My accelerometer date can be read in the register from 28h to 2Dh. Infortunatly it don´t works i don´t know how can i show the data on my pc and to stored then.
Please i need your help.
Thanks

```
uint8_t*  i;
int main(void)
{
for(i= (0x28); i= (0x2D); i++)
{
 HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0xD6, i , 1, 100);

}

// receive the 2 x 8bit data into the receive buffer
HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, 0xD7,(uint8_t*)0x2f , 6, 100);
HAL_Delay(100);
```

Comment: Well, you are not using correctly the HAL I2C functions. Check the parameters to see your error.

Comment: Here is a [link to the description](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/63/a8/8f/e3/ca/a1/4c/84/DM00173145.pdf/files/DM00173145.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00173145.pdf) your parameter passing is wrong, check the doc to be able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong understanding of how the LSM6DS0 I2C interface works and you're using the wrong I2C functions from the HAL library.

Please read section 4.1.1 of the [LSM6DS0 datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/6e/09/28/0b/01/06/42/24/DM00101533.pdf/files/DM00101533.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00101533.pdf).  Pay close attention to tables 16 through 19.  The LSM6DS0 implements multiple registers which are identified by sub-addresses.  In order to read data from a sub-address the master has to write the slave address followed by the register sub-address and then perform a *repeated start* and read from the slave address.

The HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit() and HAL_I2C_Master_Receive() functions do not support the type of I2C transfer that is required to read data from a sub-address.  HAL_I2C_Master_Receive() does not write a sub-address and does not perform a repeated start.

Instead you should be using HAL_I2C_Mem_Write() and HAL_I2C_Mem_Read().  Try something like this:

```
#define DEVICE_ADDR 0xD6
#define REG_OUT_X_XL_SUB_ADDR 0x28
#define I2C_TIMEOUT 100

HAL_StatusTypeDef ReadRegister16(uint8_t reg_addr, uint16_t *out_value)
{
    uint16_t reg_value;

    HAL_StatusTypeDef hal_status = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, DEVICE_ADDR, reg_addr, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &reg_value, sizeof(uint16_t), I2C_TIMEOUT);

    if (hal_status == HAL_OK)
    {
        *out_value = reg_val;
    }

    return hal_status;
}
```